# Initialization of anonymous class member variable with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value, std-function

I wonder if there is a workaround is such situation:

```
class A
{
    class
    {
    public:
        void setValue(int val) {i=val;}
    private:
        int i;
    } B = initB(10);

    std::function<decltype(B)(int)> initB = [this](int value)
                                            {decltype(B) temp;
                                             temp.setValue(value);
                                             return temp;};
}


//...
    A a; //crash
//...
```

I suppose it is caused by order of initialization. Variable `B` is initilized by calling an uninitilized `std::function` instance, hence the crash. By my logic, the workaround would be to initialize `std::function` first, then initialize member `B`. But then, such code is not valid:

```
class A
    {
        //error: 'B' was not declared in this scope
        std::function<decltype(B)(int)> initB = [this](int value)
                                                {decltype(B) temp;
                                                 temp.setValue(value);
                                                 return temp;};
        class
        {
        public:
            void setValue(int val) {i=val;}
        private:
            int i;
        } B = initB(10);
    }
```

I tried to make to make the `std::function` `static`, and such code works, but requires `non-constexpr/const` member, because std::function has `non-trivial destructor` - which is bad, because that requires source file, which requires creating such file, which requires some efford and destruction of my beautiful header-only class hierarchy! (I mean, I could be lazy and define this variable in the header, but then the multiple definition problem occurs). I know it might be a bad design (i'm just testing things out), but do you have any ideas how the problem can be solved without involving source files?

Comment: You are allowed to forward-declare nested classes. So you can give the class a name, and refer to it instead of using `decltype` on the data member. Or separate the definition of the nested class and the data member entirely. I'm unsure about what this merge buys you.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub Now that I look at it, I don't know why I wanted it to be anonymous. Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your example is contrived, there are times when I've needed (or its more convenient) to initialize complex objects in a similar way.

But, why use std::function<>?  Why not just use a function?

```
class A
{
    class
    {
    public:
        void setValue(int val) { i = val; }
    private:
        int i;
    } B = initB(10);

    static decltype(B) initB(int value)
    {
        decltype(B) temp;
        temp.setValue(value);
        return temp; 
    }
};
```

Although, I wouldn't normally use decltype(B); I would just give the class a name.

Comment: Maybe because then initB can be reassigned, like a function ptr, to any other std::function<...>, including user-supplied ones?

Comment: @lorro: But in this case, since both initB and B are initialized during the construction of A, there's no advantage to using std::function<>.  It would be different if, say, initB had been a static because it could have theoretically been assigned a new value to affect the construction of new instances of A (i.e. initB would be the factory to use for constructing instances of B).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I am somehow subverting your intent, but if you initialize the variables in the constructor, you can make things work.

```
#include <functional>

class A
{
  class
  {
   public:
    void setValue(int val) {i=val;}
   private:
    int i;
  } B;

  std::function<decltype(B)(int)> initB;

 public:
  A() {
    initB = [this](int value)
            {decltype(B) temp;
             temp.setValue(value);
             return temp;};
    B = initB(10);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A::initB is a value. It's not initialized at the point where you call it, because initialization is done (loosely speaking) in the order you specify member fields. You can verify this by executing the below, which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U>
T set(T& tgt, const U& src)
{
    new(&tgt) T(src);
    return tgt;
}

class A
{
    class
    {
    public:
        void setValue(int val) {i=val;}
    private:
        int i;
    } B = set(initB, [this](int value)
                        {decltype(B) temp;
                         temp.setValue(value);
                         return temp;})(10);

    std::function<decltype(B)(int)> initB;
};


int main() {
    A a;
}
```